# Replace value in R data.frame

Tags: r, replace, dataframe

I would like to replace/update values in R data.frame, please see example below:

Original data.frame originalDF contains cars, price and size columns:

```
    cars <- c("FORD", "GM")
    price <- c(10,  20)
    size <- c(1,2)  
    originalDF <- data.frame(cars=cars, price=cbind(price), size=cbind(size))

    originalDF:
    cars price size
  1 FORD    10    1
  2   GM    20    2
```

Then I want to replace/update values in the originalDF with new values from (smaller) newDF, assume newDF is a single record of sale:

```
cars <- "FORD"
price  <- 15
color  <- "white"
newDF <- data.frame(cars=cars, price=cbind(price),color=cbind(color))

newDF:
cars price color
1 FORD    15 white
```

So this is my final result.

```
modifiedDF:
  cars price
1 FORD    15
2   GM    20
```

Please note that newDF has additional values that are not included in the originalDF and that are not needed. At the same time originalDF may have columns that may not be presented in newDF and therefore cannot be updated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [R - data.frame matching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150405/r-data-frame-matching)

Answer (score 0):

Find the rows that match.  change the values.

```
rows <- originalDF$cars %in% newDF$cars
originalDF[rows, -1] <- newDF[, -1]
```

Note that the above assumes same column order for `originalDF` and `newDF`.  If this is not guaranteed, replace the `-1` in `[, ]` with the proper column names

Comment: thank you very much Ricardo, this works for this particular example, but if I need to update two fields, would it be something like this?  originalDF[rows, c("price","color")] <- newDF[, c("price","color")]

Comment: Ricardo, one more question, what if cars in originalDF are not column but rownames(originalDF), could you please suggest what to do in this case?

Comment: I think I got it, like this: rows <- rownames(originalDF) %in% rownames(newDF)

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`, you can do it quite easily:

```
library(data.table)
# Create your data
originalDF <- data.table(cars=c("FORD", "GM"), price=c(10,  20), size=c(1,2)) %>% setkey(cars)
newDF <- data.table(cars="FORD", price=15, color="white") %>% setkey(cars)
# Update originalDF
originalDF[newDF, intersect(names(originalDF), names(newDF)) := mget(paste0("i.", intersect(names(originalDF), names(newDF))))]
```

If you're not used to `data.table` manipulation, the last instruction might require some explanation.

`originalDF[newDF]` is simply a left join (left table is `originalDF`). The merging key was defined during tables creation with `setkey`. We could also set the key with `originalDF[newDF, on=.(cars=cars)]`.

And while we're joining, we modify on the fly (on the original left table) some fields, thanks to operator `:=`. We could be creating a new column (`originalDF[newDF, new_column := new_value]`, empty values would be NA), but here we decide to update all the common columns of `originalDF` and `newDF`.

Eventually, `mget` is going to retrieve the content of those columns on the right table (that's what `i` refers to, the general syntax for `data.table` is `dt[i,j,group]`, where `i` being basically defines which rows are affected, `j` which columns, and `group` how rows should be aggregated).